# Is it possible to use Lambda with model of List<ViewModel>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, lambda, editorfor

When the model is of type List, how can we use the lambda with it?

```
@model List<ViewModels.MyModel>
```

This does not work for EditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.FirstOrDefault().Value)
```

How can I bind the model with the EditorFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have iterate on it and do indexing as it is collection:

```
@for(int i =0; i <Model.Count; i ++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m=> Model[i].Value)
}
```

Comment: It worked. When I inspect the element on the browser, I noticed the id was not assigned to the control and the name of it is [0].Value. Why do you think this happened?

Comment: @Jude which id you are talking about?

Comment: id of `<input>` which was created by EditorFor.

Comment: @Jude when our model is collection name has to be indexed so that it can be posted

Comment: @Jude it's the way collection binds with model see:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: OK. By the way I am wondering the reason for downvotes as well.

Comment: @Jude I am also wondering and downvoters dont have a reason to put in my post comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Full example below:

Your Controller Code:

```
public class ModelValue
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public class TestController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      List<ModelValue> model = new List<ModelValue>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      {
         model.Add(new ModelValue { ID = i, Name = "Name " + i.ToString()  });
      }

      return View(model);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(List<ModelValue> model)
   {
      return View(model);
   }
}
```

Your View Code:

```
@model List<MVCApp.Controllers.ModelValue>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
      @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => Model[i].ID)
      @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => Model[i].Name)
      <br />
   }
   <button type="submit">Go</button>
}
```